# Masking Textbox to accept only decimals

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, regex, maskedtextbox

I am using the technique from this link to mask my textbox to accept strings that are in decimal-format (Digits with a single period).

[How to define TextBox input restrictions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103765/how-to-define-textbox-input-restrictions)

Here is the regex I put in the mask:

```
b:Masking.Mask="^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$"
```

For some odd reason, it lets me input the digits but I cannot insert the period in my textbox.

I've also validated the regex here so regex is definitely correct.

http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modify your regex with this:

```
^\d+([\.\d].{1,2})?$
```

**[DEMO](http://regexr.com?320j6)**

**EDIT:**

The above regex will also allow `123..1` that is more than 1 decimal point. so I just found the problem and fixed with the below one:

```
^(\d+)?+([\.]{1})?+([\d]{1,2})?$
```

**[DEMO](http://regexr.com?320jc)**

Comment: Oh wow it WAS the regex. I will mark this as an answer once 5 minutes pass. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm your edited answer gives me the following error:

Error 11 parsing "^(\d+)?+([\.]{1})?+([\d]{1,2})?$" - Nested quantifier +.

Comment: In .Net it will change the meaning to `"match one or more of the preceding character"` Try to `Escape` special characters as `+` (inside an @"" literal)..
so your regex will be `@"^(\d\+)?\+([\.]{1})?\+([\d]{1,2})?$"`

Comment: With using that behavior, removing the +'s worked for me: `^(\d+)?([\.]{1})?([\d]{1,2})?$`

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use the Regular Expression

```
^(\d+)?+([\.]{1})?+([\d]{1,2})?$
```

Or you can use below event

```
   bool blHasDot = false;
   private void txt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == '\b')
        {
            // Allow Digits and BackSpace char
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '.' && !blHasDot)
        {
            //Allows only one Dot Char
            blHasDot=true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```